# Implementing == operator in C# on explicit-interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, operator-overloading, equality

I have defined a struct **Coords** that explicitly implements three interfaces, each defined like this:

```
  public partial struct Coords
  {
    int           ICoordsUser.X          { get { return VectorUser.X; } }
    int           ICoordsUser.Y          { get { return VectorUser.Y; } }
    IntVector2D   ICoordsUser.Vector     { get { return VectorUser;   }
                                           set { VectorUser=value;    } }
    ICoordsCanon  ICoordsUser.Canon      { get { return this;         } } 
    ICoordsUser   ICoordsUser.Clone()    { return NewUserCoords(VectorUser);  }
    string        ICoordsUser.ToString() { return VectorUser.ToString(); }

    IEnumerable<NeighbourCoords> ICoordsUser.GetNeighbours(Hexside hexsides) { 
        return GetNeighbours(hexsides); 
    }
    int ICoordsUser.Range(ICoordsUser coords) { return Range(coords.Canon); }
  }
```

with the names `ICoordsCanon`, `ICoordsUser`, and `ICoordsCustom`. Then I have defined Value Equality on the struct like so:

```
#region Value Equality
bool IEquatable<Coords>.Equals(Coords rhs) { return this == rhs; }

public override bool Equals(object rhs) { 
  return (rhs is Coords) && this == (Coords)rhs; 
}

public static bool operator == (Coords lhs, Coords rhs) { 
  return lhs.VectorCanon == rhs.VectorCanon; 
}

public static bool operator != (Coords lhs, Coords rhs) { return ! (lhs == rhs); }
public override int GetHashCode() { return VectorUser.GetHashCode(); }

bool IEqualityComparer<Coords>.Equals(Coords lhs, Coords rhs) { return lhs == rhs; }
int  IEqualityComparer<Coords>.GetHashCode(Coords coords) {
    return coords.GetHashCode();
}
#endregion
```

However, when I perform an equality comparison with the **==** operator between values of one of the interface types, as

```
if (coordsUser1 == userCoords2) { /* whatever */ }
```

a reference comparison using **object.==** is always performed. Does anyone know how I can force value equality onto the **==** operator in such a circumstance, using C#?

Thank you in advance for any thoughts or suggestions.

[Edit]
In the example above, both **coordsUser1** and **userCoords2** are instances of **Coords** stored in variables of type **ICoordsUser**, so it is not clear to me why the defined override of **==** is not being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot define static members for an interface, you cannot define operators on an interface. Because operator overloading is resolved at compile-time, the compiler will not see any `==` operator that matches the signature given an interface type. Since `Object` defines the `==` operator for objects, and there is no better match at compile time, it will use that one.

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Cast the left-hand object to the type that defines the `==` operator.

   ```
   return (Coords)coordsUser1 == userCoords2;
   ```
2. Use the normal `Equals(object)` method. However, this will *box* your struct.

   ```
   return coordsUser1.Equals(userCoords2);
   ```
3. Force your interfaces to implement `IEquatable<T>`, and use the generic `Equals(T)` (which reduces boxing).

   ```
   return coordsUser1.Equals(userCoords2);
   ```

Comment: Method (3) is what I was using, when I wondered if there was an alternative.